# Python script called within Bash script doesn't use Python3 Interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I'm using OSX Mojave. 
Python 2.7 and Python 3.7 are installed.
I've added an alias to my ~/.bash_profile:

```
alias python='python3'
```

So, when I try to get the version of Python, It now points to python 3:

```
python -V
Python 3.7.5
```

I have a python script pythonScript.py as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
print(sys.version_info)
```

Executing this directly via **python pythonScript.py** or **./pythonScript.p**y produces:

```
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

However if I execute this from inside a bash wrapper, it is being run with Python2.7 interpreter:

```
#!/bin/bash
python pythonScript.py

sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

What do I need to do to force bash wrappers to use Python 3 interpreter via alias?

I am aware I can run via **python3** pythonScript.py within the bash wrapper, but I wish to know if it is possible to have an alias at this level so as to just use **python**

Comment: Sounds like you have mistaken something, but... under what user you run the script?

Comment: Run with local user without sudo @Emil

Comment: That's because your `bashrc` is only for your user in an interactive shell. Most likely, the alias isn't being seen by your script. You can just prefix `./pythonScript.py` with `python3` as such: `python3 ./pythonScript.py` and it will work.

Comment: You are not using you alias to call the python script, try using `python -m pythonScript.py` instead of `./pythonScript.py` instead.  You should also consider using virtual environments to avoid confusion

Comment: I cannot replicate this.  Is `#!/usr/bin/env python3` failing to access the correct executable on your system?  Are you sure `./pythonScript.py` is working when called direct from the shell?  BTW the `alias` seems to be irrelevant to this problem—since `python3` is *explicitly* specified in the `#!` line, the error you're reporting really seems to be about failure to correctly interpret and follow that `#!` line—the discussion of the alias and `.bashrc`, etc, is just going to muddy the water.

Comment: Please see edited description. I've confirmed that, within the bash script, calling via ./pythonScript.py uses Python 3.7 but python pythonScript.py uses Python 2.7. So, in essence I need to ensure the alias I set up also effects bash wrappers, as I currently isn't. Thanks.

Comment: OK, so this question is really https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases  and the one-line summary of the best answer is "don't do that!"   If `pythonScript.py` is written in Python 3, in your bash script, you should unambiguously launch it in `python3` rather than relying on the alias—or, remove the `python` entirely and rely on the Python script's own `#!` line.

Comment: Thanks jez. Moderators, close if a duplicate. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Even if the alias *was* seen by the script, alias expansion in non-interactive shells is disabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliases don't work in scripts. What you are trying to do is a bad idea. Rather call the Python script directly with `./pythonScript.py` instead of `python pythonScript.py` and put the correct interpreter in pythonScript.py with a shebang (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env python3`).

If you really want to do this anyway create a function in the wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function python {
    python3 "$@"
}

python pythonScript.py
```

If you need this to work without modifying the wrapper script then you can export the function prior to calling the wrapper script:

```
function python {
    python3 "$@"
}
export -f python
./wrapper_script.sh
```